# What causes those horizontal color streaks on my printer's output?

Tags: printing, printer, laser-printer

Ever since I acquired it, less than a hundred pages ago, this printer's paper output has featured horizontal bands - the denser the color, the denser the streaks.

The printer is a [Canon i-SENSYS MF-8340Cdn](http://www.canon-europe.com/For_Home/Product_Finder/Multifunctionals/Laser/i-SENSYS_MF8340Cdn/).

The original test image :

[image: Original test image]

The same test image, printed and scanned :

[image: Scanned test image]

The printer's diagnostics tell me that the toner cartridges are full. I see no contamination of any sort inside the printer.

Can anyone tell me what is going on ?

Comment: It is probably best if you return it as defective.

Comment: Looks like dirty or defective ink cartridges. Have you tried new ink cartridges?

Comment: The integrated toner/drum bits are clean as far as I can see.

Comment: I'm now hunting for an answer from Canon - I'm not holding my breath. I'll post the answer here if Canon solves the problem before Superuser !

Comment: dont mess with it; return it as defective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'starter' toner cartridge that came with the printer were defective. I replaced them and the problem simply disappeared. I probably should have started with that...

Answer (score 0):

Usually this indicates that your heads are dirty and need serious cleaning. if the stripes were vertical, that would indicate fuser or transfer rollers, but horizontal means that the problem originates from the application of toner. look at this article on cleaning print heads: http://www.ehow.com/how_5195058_clean-clogged-canon-printhead.html

Comment: This is a laser printer - so there are no print heads that might get clogged (when that happen on inkjet printers, I wipe them with a moist tissue)... I'll take a closer look at toner-related bits.